# Missing a logic on table based printing in Java

Tags: java

I recently wrote some code that is supposed to make a string into a box.
If the input is "hello", The output should look like this:

```
hello
e   l
l   l
l   e
olleh
```

I have pretty much all of the code and I made it into a box, except I can't seem to make the letters line up. I know the part where I messed up, I just don't know how to fix it. The part that is messed up is in quotations and is commented. Here is the code, Thank you!:

```
int num = 0;
for (int i=1;i<=word.length();i++){
    for (int a=1;a<=word.length();a++){
        if(i>1 && i<word.length() && a>1 && a<word.length())
            System.out.print(" ");
        else
            //"System.out.print(word.charAt(num));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: @SrikanthA Huh? The above is sufficient

Comment: I tried num = num ++ in various places around the code but none seemed to work

Comment: @Torbs - see my answer, num is not even necessary

Comment: You are using `i=1; i<=amountOfTimes`     This is bad. Use `i=0; i<amountOfTimes`

Comment: @Torbs. Please check my answer - with more simpler and easy to understand logic

Answer (score 1):

You could have your `String` reversed first, and store it in a `char[]` array. (As I forgot to use [`StringBuilder#reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse())).

You can then iterate with 2 `for` loops as you did, with some conditions for the top, bottom and middle lines as follows:

The trick is using the original string for the top and left part and the reverse one on the right and bottom one.

Also note that you're starting from index 1~`word.lenght()` and this is not what you want since when printing each character you start from index `0` not `1`

```
public class WordSquare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "hello";
        int num = 0;
        char[] reverseWord = new char[word.length()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverseWord[counter] = word.charAt(i);
            counter++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            counter = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    System.out.print(word.charAt(j));
                } else {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
                    } else if (j < (word.length() - 1)) {
                        if (i < (word.length() - 1)) {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        } else {
                            System.out.print(reverseWord[j]);
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(reverseWord[i]);
                    }
                } 
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces:

```
hello
e   l
l   l
l   e
olleh
```

Comment: your output does not match OP's

Comment: Yeah, already saw that. Fixing it

Comment: @ScaryWombat see edit, it's fixed now. A variable mistake

Answer (score 1):

I just assumed that you had to do it inside the two for loops so I just added to the loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= word.length() - 1; i++){
        for (int a = 0; a <= word.length() - 1; a++){
            if(i > 0 && i < word.length() - 1 && a > 0 && a < word.length() - 1) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            } else if(i == word.length() - 1) {
                System.out.print(word.charAt(word.length()-1-a));
            } else if(a != word.length() - 1) {
                System.out.print(word.charAt((a+i)%word.length()));
            } else {
                System.out.print(word.charAt((a-i)%word.length()));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Here's the same thing in only two else statements

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= word.length() - 1; i++){
        for (int a = 0; a <= word.length() - 1; a++){
            if(i > 0 && i < word.length() - 1 && a > 0 && a < word.length() - 1) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            } else if (a == 0 || i == 0) {
                System.out.print(word.charAt((a+i)%word.length()));
            } else {
                System.out.print(word.charAt((2*(word.length()-1)-a-i)%word.length()));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String word = "hello";
        System.out.println(word);
        for (int i = 1; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
            for (int j = 0; j < word.length() - 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(word.charAt(word.length()-i-1));
        }
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString());
```

**Output:**

```
hello
e   l
l   l
l   e
olleh
```

Comment: nicest version so far I think

Comment: For people who thinks that i just copied  **Anthony C** answer with updates. This is not what happened !!This similarity !! Even i found it so freaking unbelievable !!

Comment: @Null, Great minds think alike.:)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  public void print(String word){
    System.out.println(word);
    for (int i=1;i<word.length()-1;i++){
      System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
      for (int j=0;j<word.length()-2;j++){
        System.out.print(" ");

      }
      System.out.println(word.charAt(word.length()-i-1));
    }
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString());
  }
```

Interesting homework question btw

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

Try this, More Simpler logic

```
public class SchoolAssignment
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String input = "hello";
    String middleSpaces  = null;

    //Determine amount of space in middle rows
    StringBuilder middleSpace = new StringBuilder();
    middleSpace.append("%"); 
    middleSpace.append(String.valueOf(input.length()-2));
    middleSpace.append("s"); 
    middleSpaces = String.format(middleSpace.toString(), " ");

    //print first line
    System.out.println(input);

    //print middle lines
    for(int i = 1; i <= input.length() - 2; i++){
        StringBuilder middleLine = new StringBuilder();
        middleLine.append(input.charAt(i));
        middleLine.append(middleSpaces); 
        middleLine.append(input.charAt(input.length() - 1 - i)); 
        System.out.println(middleLine.toString());
    }

    //print last line
    StringBuilder lastLine = new StringBuilder();
    lastLine.append(input);
    lastLine=lastLine.reverse(); 
    System.out.println(lastLine);

   }
}
```

Comment: This uses only one for loop, and no if conditions. Comparatively efficient.
Please mark as answered if it answers the best way